# C++: Deallocating 3d vector

Tags: c++, vector

For slic superpixel creation for a 3d medical image I've created a 3d vector 
(std::vector of std::vector of std::vector holding DataStr objects). With the dimensions of the image (~150 x 150 x 150). DataStr is a struct that stores voxel information such as a vector of pointers to its neighbors in the same 3d vector. Working with this turns out to be much faster than looping through the image with a neighborhood iterator or KdTree nearest neighbor search as this information has to be available for each iteration of the slic algorithm. Furthermore, it is in comparison very convenient to work with it. However, the deallocation of the 3d vector takes ~4 minutes, when the 3d vector runs out of scope. Can anyone tell me why this is the case and how I can avoid this? Thanks!

Edit:

First time asking a question here, thanks for your patience :-)!

```
struct DataStr{
  std::vector<DataStr*> neighbors;
  float cmpVal;
  int association;
  cv::Mat index;
  float intensity;
  DataStr() :association{ -1 }, cmpVal{ std::numeric_limits<float>::max() }{}
};
```

Above is the struct in the .hpp file. Below definition and initialization of dat

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<DataStr>>> dat;
for (int i{ 0 }; i < imgDim[0]; ++i)
{
    dat.resize(imgDim[0]);
    for (int j{ 0 }; j < imgDim[1]; ++j)
    {
        dat[i].resize(imgDim[1]);
        for (int k{ 0 }; k < imgDim[2]; ++k)
        {
            dat[i][j].resize(imgDim[2], DataStr{});
        }
    }
}
```

imgDim is 3d array of image dimension.

```
 for (it_nImg.GoToBegin(), it_nMask.GoToBegin(), it_nCent.GoToBegin();    !it_nImg.IsAtEnd(); ++it_nImg, ++it_nMask, ++it_nCent)
{       
    auto  idx = it_nMask.GetIndex();
    DataStr* str = &dat[idx[0]][idx[1]][idx[2]];
    (*str).intensity = it_nImg.GetCenterPixel();
    (*str).index = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 3) << idx[0], idx[1], idx[2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < it_nMask.Size(); ++i)
    {
        auto tmpIdx = it_nMask.GetIndex(i);
        (*str).neighbors.push_back(&dat[tmpIdx[0]][tmpIdx[1]][tmpIdx[2]]);
    }

}
```

it_n* are image neighborhood iterators from itk library to fill the neighborhood vector in DataStr for each voxel in the image. it_nMask.Size() is the size of the chosen neighborhood. it_n*.GetIndex() provides a 3 element array of the 3d voxel index. Thanks a lot.

Edit edit:

If I store the indices of the neighboring voxels instead of pointers to them the deallocation takes only 0.5 seconds. Is this because the pointers to DataStr are 8 byte in length and an int is only 4 byte on my machine?

Comment: Your question is a big vague.  Perhaps you could add a code snippet so we could see what you're doing?

Comment: Also, have you compared to using a vector of size `150 * 150 * 150` and providing your own inline index function, `int index(x, y, z) { return 150 * 150 * x + 150 * y + z; }`?

Comment: What does the `DataStr` destructor do? What does the class look like? And please show us some *code*, code says more than a thousand pictures. Preferably try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add code or other important information.

Comment: As for the performance problem, there is a very simple way of *not* having this problem: Don't pass the data around by value but by reference. If there's only one of this vector, and there's no direct need to copy it, then *don't* copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that the performance problem is in the destructor.  Making vectors of vectors of vectors causes `150 + 150 * 150` allocations and deallocations.  If you don't see it on allocation, I suspect it's because it's amortized over your usage.

Is it acceptable in your case to say

```
std::vector<DataStr> dat;
int dat_size = imgDim[0] * imgDim[1] * imgDim[2];
dat.reserve(dat_size);
// No need to loop and initialize, the default constructor
// will do that for you.
```

Then in your big loop, replace this line

```
DataStr* str = &dat[idx[0]][idx[1]][idx[2]];
```

with this one

```
DataStr& str = dat[dat_index(idx[0], idx[1], idx[2])];
```

(and then there's some details, because I used a reference instead of a pointer).  Here I've defined a helper function,

```
inline int dat_index(int x, int y, int z) {
    return imgDim[0] * imgDim[1] * x + imgDim[0] * y + z;
}
```

which might be slightly different depending on how you are thinking of your indices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your right, for the initialization your approach is easier and I don't see any drawbacks. Could you elaborate on "amortized over usage"? The first two snippets take a fraction of a second to run. The  third snippet about 1 minute, but it depends strongly on the chosen neighborhood (3x3x3 neigh ~12s, 4x4x4 neigh ~22s, 7x7x7 neigh ~1min). Therefore this 1 minute doesn't seem to be linked to the allocation process.

Comment: When you allocate (and I'm guessing, because I only see some of what you do), I think the set of all the needed allocations (the values in all the third-level vectors) get allocated as those vectors grow to need them.  So maybe you you see 20,000 tiny delays instead of one big one.  Or maybe it's just that your memory allocator is faster to allocate than deallocate.  These are just guesses.

Comment: BTW, if you're happy with the answer, the custom is to click the accept checkbox.  It signals to StackOverflow that the question is answered, and it distributes pixie dust to encourage answerers.

Comment: Thanks. This approach reduced the time from 230 to 26 seconds.